# Mcrypt encryption C# equivalent of PHP (Rijndael 128 with 32bit hexKey)

Tags: c#, php, encryption, mcrypt, rijndael

I am sorry if this was asked/answered elsewhere but I was unable to find it.

I am currently trying to duplicate the result of PHP mcrypt in C#. PHP being the back-end server. I am using Rijndael 128 in ECB mode with a 256bit (32 char) hexKey.

Now I know that ECB is less secure then CBC and that mcrypt is depreciated but I am not the one who developed the back-end and have no choice to do in this manner (trust me I asked).

Test password: **testPassword**

hexKey: **2619eeaed2cb05f60f298b7af8e565e4f155dd76821865994d4e660d7c041281**

P.S. the hexKey is not the actualkey we are using ;)

Here is my code in PHP

```
$key = $this->hexToStr([key]);
$text = $password;
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

private function hexToStr($hex) {
$string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex) - 1; $i+=2) {
    $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i] . $hex[$i + 1]));
}
return $string;
}
```

And my code in C#

```
    public string EncryptStringRijndael(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            string cipherText;
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

            var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged
            {
                Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HexStringToString(hexKey)),
                Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                BlockSize = 128,
                KeySize = 256,
            };

            var encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(rijndael.Key, null);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream
            (
                memoryStream,
                encryptor,
                CryptoStreamMode.Write
            );
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            cipherText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cipherTextBytes);
            //cipherText = StringToHexString(tempText);

            return cipherText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public static string HexStringToString(string hexString)
    {
        try
        {
            string ascii = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                String hs = string.Empty;

                hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
                uint decval = Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
                char character = Convert.ToChar(decval);
                ascii += character;
            }
            return ascii;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public static string StringToHexString(string originalString)
    {
        string outp = string.Empty;
        char[] value = originalString.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char L in value)
        {
            int V = Convert.ToInt32(L);
            outp += string.Format("{0:x}", V);
        }
        return outp;
    }
```

PHP result: G .�g��/D>�Y�5

C# result: ???u\0??9?`???

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and **does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding** that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Note: encryption is byte based, not character so displaying encrypted data will not produce anything usable. If you need to display encrypted data for debugging use hexadecimal.

Comment: Interesting, a 256-bit key that is no more secure than a 128-bit key and then ECB mode which is not secure. Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: I am aware of all of this, but sadly I do not have control over the back-end and the dev which is taking care of the back-end does not want to change the encryption... :/